# Method to pull specific lines from an external text file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am given a text file containing hundreds of line of information, and am tasked with pulling lines with a specific strings out. The issue is that after the line with the string being searched for is found, I also need to pull the 7 lines above it as-well.

I know this solution works for pulling specific line number. However I don't know what line number needs to be pulled, just the string on the line, along with 7 lines above the line, with the string I need.

```
file = File.open "file.txt"

n.times{ file.gets }
p $_

file.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `target?` be a method that takes a line from the file as an argument and returns `true` or `false`, depending upon whether the lines meets the matching criterion.

**Code**

```
def doit(fname)
  arr = []
  File.foreach(fname).with_object([]) do |line, a|
    arr.shift if arr.size == 8
    arr << line    
    if target?(line) && arr.size == 8
      a << arr
      arr = []        
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

Let's create a test file.

```
TARGET_LINES = ["Mary had a little lamb", "whose fleece was", "white as snow"]
a = (1..28).map { |i| "line #{i}" } 
b = [*a[0,7],  TARGET_LINES[1],
     *a[8,10], TARGET_LINES[2],
     *a[18,9], TARGET_LINES[0],
     a[27]]
FName = 'test'
File.write(FName, b.join("\n"))
  #=> 261
```

See what we have (skipping some lines).

```
puts File.read(FName)
line 1
line 2
...
line 7
whose fleece was
line 9
line 10
...
line 18
white as snow
line 19
line 20
...
line 27
Mary had a little lamb
line 28
```

Now create a `target?` method:

```
def target?(line)
  TARGET_LINES.include?(line.chomp)
end
```

and execute `doit`:

```
puts doit(FName)
line 1
line 2
...
line 7
whose fleece was
line 12
line 13
...
line 18
white as snow
line 21
line 22
...
line 27
Mary had a little lamb
```

See the docs [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) and [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) and [Array#rotate](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate). Note that `IO` class methods such as `foreach` are often invoked with the receiver `File`. This is permitted because `File` is a subclass of `IO`. (`File < IO #=> true`).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is supposed to be a Ruby question, but sometimes other tools make it easier to get the results.

Did you know about [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)? :

```
$ cat long_file.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
target
line 11
line 12
line 13
line 14

$ grep -B 7 target long_file.txt
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
target
```